# remove WebRTC and add zeroMQ in an android app

Tags: android, webrtc, zeromq

How to I remove WebRTC and add ZeroMQ to my android app?

Should I reverse the steps I did to add the WebRTC and then add ZeroMQ functionality?
Or is there a different approach?

Comment: That is impossible to answer in the abstract. ZeroMQ does not do the same things that WebRTC does.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, well WebRTC is a protocol built on top of RTP, which is intended for the non-guaranteed delivery of time critical data (video frames, audio, etc), with no guarantee of order of delivery either.

In contrast, ZMQ is a message oriented Actor Model framework with useful design patterns, guaranteed delivery (assuming the network stays up), and is very good for applications that need to ship messages around.

They are quite different. Am I right in assuming that you've started off using WebRTC (possibly due to familiarity) and have run into the limitation inherent in any protocol based on UDP (which is what RTP uses)?

If you're to use ZMQ, you have have to use it at both ends of every communication path on which you wish to use it. You cannot, for example, have ZMQ on the Android app talking to a WebRTC server. ZMQ speaks to ZMQ, and nothing else.

The good thing is that WebRTC (RTP) is similar. So if you're already using WebRTC, that might mean you control all the software. That means you can change it to use ZMQ. [The alternative, e.g. the other end of the WebRTC link was some server system that could not be change, would prevent you changing just your Android App over to ZMQ.]

As to replacing WebRTC with ZMQ, well that very much depends on what it is you're trying to send. Fundamentally ZMQ deals in messages. A message is an array of bytes. The bytes for a message are transmitted as a block from sender to receiver in a single send/receive operation. If that doesn't fit (e.g. you have a video stream with no obvious demarcation between logical chunks of video) then you may run into problems.

Often people use something like Google Protocol Buffers to define message classes which they then serialise to byte arrays, and it's these that are sent in a message. The receiving end passes the received byte array at the deserialiser, reconstituting the class as was.

Good luck